nested case class generic filter method
I have some nested case classes that may look like the following:
case class Lowest(intVal: Int, stringVal: String)
case class Mid   (lowestSeq: Seq[Lowest])
case class High  (midSeq: Seq[Mid])

So if I had a class of Mid I could easily do
myMid.lowestSeq.filter(_.intVal == 42)

but I would like to create a custom filter method where I can filter Lowest elements based on a variable. I don't mind writing some custom method like the following
case class Mid   (lowestSeq: Seq[Lowest]){
  def filterLowest(/*predicate*/): Seq[Lowest] = {
    lowestSeq.filter(/*predicate*/)
  }
}

case class High   (midSeq: Seq[Mid]){
  def filterLowest(/*predicate*/): Seq[Lowest] = {
    midSeq.foldLeft[Seq[Lowest]](Seq.empty){case => (acc, mid)
      acc :+ mid.filterLowest(/*predicate*/)
    }
  }
}

But I'm having a hard time understanding how I define the predicate
For example if calling on an instance of High I want to be able to do the following
val allIntValsEq42    = myHigh.filterLowest(/*???*/intVal == 42)
val allStringValsEqYo = myHigh.filterLowest(/*???*/stringVal == 42)

How can you pass in a predicate in this way for the Mid or High class?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes, that is correct

Well all you need is a predicate for Lowest and a predicate is nothing more than a function that returns Boolean so all you need is:
predicate: Lowest => Boolean

But, we can improve your setup a little to make this more efficient:
final case class Lowest (intVal: Int, stringVal: String)
final case class Mid (lowestSeq: Seq[Lowest])

final case class High (midSeq: Seq[Mid]) {
  def filterLowest(predicate: Lowest => Boolean): Seq[Lowest] =
    midSeq.flatMap(id => mid.lowestSeq.filter(predicate))
}

Which then you can use just like when filtering the Seq directly like:
// Using placeholder syntax:
myHigh.filterLowest(_.stringVal == 42)

// Using full lambda syntax:
myHigh.filterLowest(low => low.stringVal == 42)

// Using an auxiliary function:
def lowChecker(low: Lowest): Boolean = ???
myHigh.filterLowest(lowChecker)


Can you provide an example of what I would put as the predicate when calling filterLowest in this case? Can you just do _.intVal == 42 or something similar?

@lSteveol yes you can do just that, is just a function. I added the details to the answer. This is basic Scala which should have been covered by any course / book / tutorial so I would recommend picking one.
